# Converting gray scale BMP to full color

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, bmp

I'm learning some basic image processing and using a gray scale BMP file to work some algorithms but I'd like to convert my code to put out color BMP files instead of gray scale. I'm using the EasyBMP library and have the following to read in and write to my BMP file:

```
bool Image::readFromBMPFile(const std::string & inputFileName){
    bool success = true;
    // use BMP object to read image
    BMP inputImage;

    success = inputImage.ReadFromFile(inputFileName.c_str() );
    if( success ){
        // allocate memory for image (deleting old, if exists)
        m_numRows = inputImage.TellHeight();
        m_numCols = inputImage.TellWidth();
        if( m_pixels != NULL ){
            // deallocate old memory
            delete [] m_pixels;
        }
        m_pixels = new double[m_numRows * m_numCols];
        // copy pixels
        for( int r = 0; r < m_numRows; ++r ){
            for( int c = 0; c < m_numCols; ++c ){
                RGBApixel pixelVal = inputImage.GetPixel(c, r);
                double val = (double) pixelVal.Blue + (double) pixelVal.Green + (double) pixelVal.Red;
                val = (val / 3.0 + 0.5);
                m_pixels[r * m_numCols + c] = val;
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

bool Image::writeToBMPFile(const std::string & outputFileName){
    bool success = true;
    if( m_pixels != NULL ){
    // create bitmap image
    BMP outputImage;
    outputImage.SetSize(m_numCols, m_numRows);
    outputImage.SetBitDepth( 24 );

    double maxVal = m_pixels[0];
    double minVal = m_pixels[0];
    // Maximum and minimum values
    for( int i = 1; i < m_numRows * m_numCols; ++i ){
        if( m_pixels[i] > maxVal ){
            maxVal = m_pixels[i];
        }
        if( m_pixels[i] <= minVal ){
            minVal = m_pixels[i];
        }
    }
    for( int r = 0; r < m_numRows; ++r ){
        for( int c = 0; c < m_numCols; ++c ){
            // get pixel value and clamp between 0 and 255
            double val = 255.0 * (m_pixels[r * m_numCols + c] - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal);
            if( val < 0 ){
                val = 0;
            }
            if( val > 255 ){
                val = 255;
            }
            // set output color based on mapping
            RGBApixel pixelVal;
            pixelVal.Blue = (int)val;
            pixelVal.Green = (int)val;
            pixelVal.Red = (int)val;
            outputImage.SetPixel(c, r, pixelVal);
        }
    }
    // write to file
    success = outputImage.WriteToFile( outputFileName.c_str() );

    } else {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

What kind of steps would I try to make my program compatible with RGB images?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I'm trying to use the pixelVal.Blue, pixelVal.Green, and pixelVal.Red individually instead of averaging them as is done at val = (val / 3.0 + 0.5). That way I can have m_pixels[] store 3 values (BGR) in triplets?